# Joining tables to feature classes in batch using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins

I need some help with batch processing using python. I am trying to join fields to multiple point features classes from multiple dbf tables (650 feature classes and tables). Names of the dbf tables match names from each feature class. I have got the script so far; I am not sure where I went wrong as the script runs but feature classes are not updated with the join. I am using arcpy.joinField.management instead of Add Join because I want to update the feature classes directly without having to create feature layer and save.

Is that where I am wrong?

My script so far is below:

```
 import arcpy, os  
 from arcpy import env  
 # Add variables 
 GDB1 = r"C:\test\GDB1.gdb"  
 GDB2 = r"C:\test\GDB2.gdb"  
 joinField = "Work_ID"  
 env.workspace = GDB1  
 #Join tables  
 for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():          
     env.workspace = GDB2  
     for table in arcpy.ListTables():  
         try:  
             if table() == fc():  
                 try:                              

                        arcpy.JoinField_management(GDB1 + os.sep + fc,      joinField, GDB2 + os.sep + table, joinField, "")

                except:  
                       arcpy.AddMessage("Could not join ")  
                       pass  
    except:  
            pass  
env.workspace = GDB1
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a table view? This would update your join automatically when any of the datasets are updated.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE and thank you for your contribution. Please consider adding more detail such as a hyperlink to table view information or possibly code highlighting how the OP could integrate table views into their workflow.